# getAttribute in template

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

in action i can:

```
$this->getUser()->getAttribute('id');
```

but how can i make it in template and in model in Symfony 1.4?

http://webmozarts.com/2009/07/01/why-sfcontextgetinstance-is-bad/ what use instead of getInstance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its very simple.

In template:

```
$sf_user->getAttribute('id');
```

In Model:

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getAttribute('id');
```

Comment: thanks, but this is safety? http://webmozarts.com/2009/07/01/why-sfcontextgetinstance-is-bad/ what use instead of getInstance?

Comment: @MartinSowning: Yes. But as your link tells: If possible, avoid singleton.

Comment: what use instead of sfContext::getInstance()? is any possibility?

Comment: Instead of using 'sfContext::getInstance(), you should pass the user id through as a parameter in the function. i.e. JobsTable::getUserJobs($this->getUser()->getId());